# What javascript fallback does best simulate html5 form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polyfills

I have built an app that validates forms client side with html5. I'm looking for the javascript-implementation that best emulates this behavior in older browsers.

Important qualities are:

- As similar behavior as possible.
- As little modification of css/html as possible
- As little functionality besides field-validation built in as possible

Comment: And what is html5 validation?

Comment: You can try jquery validation plugin from bassistance

Comment: @JanHančič form validation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS tricks has a nice article on the fallback process here:
http://css-tricks.com/progressively-enhancing-html5-forms/

They also suggest a project such as this
http://code.google.com/p/webforms2/

Which includes some of the HTML5 form validation goodness

*Just remember to always check server side too when it comes to validation :)*