# html5 form validation (without submitting)

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9, validation

I have a modal div that appears in my app, it contains form elements, but I don't want to submit the form, the values get written into other DOM elements on the page.

I do however, want to ensure the fields in this modal are valid before allowing the 'Ok' action to execute.

I need this to work in IE9 (which IIRC does not support `.checkValidity()`)

So, what I'm asking is, when I click an Ok button (not a submit button) how can I validate and show what's invalid on this form, without submitting.

I would prefer to use as much html5 functionality (`<input required />` and such) as possible.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/AtHas/

Comment: If you want it to work in a wide range of browsers, [use JavaScript](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). If you only use HTML5, you're not going to get it to work in all browsers.

Comment: pretty much, its just not ready yet.

Comment: I just need it to work in IE9+ (and chrome would be nice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has a plugin for validation that can be made to handle what you are trying to accomplish.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: I actually used jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.  I really like that plugin, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a similar question:

[What javascript fallback does best simulate html5 form validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355626/what-javascript-fallback-does-best-simulate-html5-form-validation)

Form validation in html5 does not work in all browsers, we just have to wait, and implement javascript in the meantime.